# How to modify the title "All paths lead to hubs: the case of water isotopologues" such that it will be one statement only?

Tags: word-choice, titles, scientific-publishing, phrasing

We are in the process of publishing a paper in Communications Chemistry, for which we devised the following title:

> **All paths lead to hubs: the case of water isotopologues**

However, the editor asked us to change the title because it does not comply the journal's (quite broad and inexact) house standards, specifically:

> ***The title should summarize the key findings in a single statement of***
> ***15 words or fewer*.**

It also turned out that they would not allow a title which contains  two (more or less) isolated statements with long dashes, commas, colons, semicolons, *etc.*

To treat this situation, we thought of the following form:

> **All paths lead to hubs in spectroscopic networks of water isotopologues**

but this is not really what we would like to say. The correct meaning would be the following:

> **All paths lead to hubs in spectroscopic networks such as in those of water isotopologues**

but this does not sound like a title. Is there any way to reflect the latter meaning in a title which retains the witty paraphrasis "all paths lead to hubs"? Thank you in advance for your help.

To give the title a context, this is the abstract of our manuscript:

> In spectroscopic networks, where the nodes are quantum states and the edges are transitions connecting states, hubs are the most important states with the largest number of incident transitions. Utilizing network paths probed via precision metrology, absolute energies have been derived, with a 10-digit accuracy, for almost 200 hubs in the experimental networks of H₂<sup>16</sup>O and H₂<sup>18</sup>O. These hubs, lying on the ground vibrational states of both species and the bending fundamental of H₂<sup>16</sup>O, participate in tens of thousands of observed transitions. Relying on the same hubs and other states, benchmark-quality line lists were assembled, which supersede and improve, by three orders of magnitude, the accuracy of the vast amount of measurements published in hundreds of papers dealing with Doppler-limited spectroscopy. Due to the omnipresence of water, these ultraprecise line lists could be applied to calibrate high-resolution spectra and serve ongoing and upcoming space missions.

Comment: A link to the Wikipedia definition of an [isotopologue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopologue) might be useful for the non-chemists here (or for folks like me who only studied chemistry at the undergrad level). I still don't fully understand your abstract even after reading that, but at least I managed to rule out several potential misunderstandings.

Comment: Also, your "*All paths lead to hubs in spectroscopic networks such as in those of water isotopologues*" is exactly 15 words. Just saying. :)

Comment: (And the second "in" could and IMO should be dropped to get it down to just 14, while making it more idiomatic.)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen It would be useful for me if you could pinpoint these unclear points, because we are trying to make the abstract more understandable for a broader audience.

Comment: Honestly, most of my confusion simply stems from unfamiliarity with the terminology, and the fact that I'm probably outside your target audience even in the broadest sense. My main initial confusion was that I was unfamiliar with the term "isotopologue" and my brain at first tried to parse it as a combination of *iso*- and *topology*, rather than as a portmanteau of *isotope* and *analogue*. As for the rest, I think I'm starting to get it after several re-readings. I'm still unclear on some details (like *how* did you probe the paths) but those may be out of scope for the abstract.

Comment: Anyway, I do have a couple of questions that might help me suggest improvements: (1) Are there any spectroscopic networks where all paths do *not* lead to hubs? (2) Does your current paper actually include novel general results for networks other than those of water isotopologues, or is that something for future work? (3) Did you (i.e. authors of this paper) derive the absolute energies for these hub states and assemble the line lists? (If not, who did? If yes, why the passive voice?)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Thanks for your comments. (0) In these networks, the (weights of the) edges can be measured with experimental techniques (the parenthetical part is never included in the literature due to negligence). A sequence of these edges forms a path, where the edge weights can be measured. This is the meaning of "probing a path".  (1) Of course, "all paths lead to hubs" is not a mathematically exact wording, it is just to say that these hubs are of crucial importance, which can be characterized by measuring these paths.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen (2) It contains general network results from our previous *Nat. Commun.* study, where we proposed a methodology for the use of network theory in the design of spectroscopic experiments. So they are not new results. (3) You must be right. We prefer the passive voice because several journals do not allow the personal pronouns as subjects. Maybe the present perfect tense could make the meaning clearer?

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications! What I was mainly trying to get at with my questions (1) and (2) is whether just "*All paths lead to hubs in spectroscopic networks*" could be a pithy summary of your key findings. Regarding (3), that's IMO a bizarre policy and one I've never heard of before. Of course if the journal demands it then that's what you have to do (or publish elsewhere), but I wonder if you're interpreting it too strictly here. If you can get away with it, IMO active voice ("we derive", "we assemble") would sound _much_ nicer and clearer here. If not, at least go for present tense.

Comment: … Or, if the prohibition is strictly about _pronouns_ as subjects, would something like "the authors derive absolute energies" work? (For the line lists I might still go with "are assembled" just to avoid repetition, although that's mostly a subjective matter of style.)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Thanks for your helpful comments. I really appreciate them. The pronoun "we" might also be slightly confusing in some cases, because it sometimes includes the reader, and sometimes not (of course, not in the case of the abstract). Is it a good practice that the authors of the actual study are talking about themselves as authors? It sounds a bit conceited, doesn't it?

Comment: I wouldn't say so. Knowing what's been done (and described) in this paper by the authors, rather than by someone else some time ago, is kind of crucial information for the reader IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since, if I understand correctly, the water isotopologues are just one example for spectroscopic networks and since all paths lead to hubs in all spectroscopic networks, the example of the water isotopologues seems superfluous in the title and a sufficient and more concise title would be "All paths lead to hubs in spectroscopic networks" in my opinion.

---

*Edit after your comments*

If, as you say, "water isotopologues have these (spectroscopic) networks, they are not networks themselves", then the following seems an elegant possibility:

> All paths lead to hubs in the spectroscopic networks of water isotopologues

---

*Edit after your abstract*

Your abstract seems to imply the following summary of your research:

> Hubs participate in tens of thousands of observed transitions between the nodes of spectroscopic networks   *(15 words)*

Or possibly, since your proposed title says "all paths":

> Hubs participate in all (observed) transitions between the nodes of spectroscopic networks of water isotopologues   *(14 or 15 words)*

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer. Yeah, that's the case, water is just an example. However, this example is studied experimentally in the manuscript, so I would be useful to include water in the title for better searchability (a part of the target audience is interested only in the details on water).

Comment: Okay. The problem is that I have no idea what your proposed title means. Is "all paths lead to" the result of your experiment or just a figure of speech? If it is a figure of speech, it needs to go. –– Can you post your abstract? Reading that will make it easier to understand what the title needs to say.

Comment: If water isotopologues is the one case you specifically study, but the work is also applicable to other spectroscopic networks, then you about _“All paths lead to hubs in water isotopologues and other spectroscopic networks”_?

Comment: @Ben Sure, it is now included in the body of my question.

Comment: @gidds Thanks for your comment. The problem is that water isotopologues have these (spectroscopic) networks, they are not networks themselves.

Comment: @TobiR I have added another suggestion to my answer.

Comment: @Ben Thanks for your suggestions. I will discuss them with the corresponding author.